# Detect QuickTime .MOV Files Using FFMPEG in Command Line

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I check whether a video file (without an extension on the file name) is a .MOV file using FFMPEG?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i filename` should spit out information about a file and exit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loot at the first 4 bytes, if it is `moov` or `mdat`, it is probablly a .mov (or .mp4 or .m4v, or m4a, or m4b, as these are supersets of mov)

Comment: How do I look at the first 4 bytes using PowerShell?

Comment: I have no idea. powershell didn't exist the last time I used windows.